Single gang to double with a switch
I'm trying to turn a single gang outlet into a 2 gang outlet. I got the old outlet and box out and the new box in. Now l'm trying to figure out how to wire 2 outlets from the wires shown as well as keep the switch functional. The 2 black wires were tied together from the old outlet, I assume this is incorrect but im not sure.




Having only one hot wire (presumably the red) connected to the outlet is really odd when there are two neutrals.  There's also no ground.

Is that outlet controlled by the switch?
If so and you both the new outlets controlled by the switch, then just add two black or red short wires to the red wire(switched hot) with a wire nut(like the two black wires) to each outlet hot screw(brass).  Do the same with the white neutral wires to the outlets neutral(silver)screw/s.
To have one outlet switched and one always hot, instead of adding the second outlet to the red, you add it to the black wires.  Add a short black wire from the two blacks to the new second outlet, plus a short white/neutral wire to the white wires.
